# What's the best python regex for the special text?

Tags: python, regex

hi，I have a log file，the file content is below：

```
[ 06-15 14:07:48.377 15012:15012 D/ViewRootImpl ]
ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0

[ 06-15 14:07:48.397  3539: 4649 D/AudioService ]
active stream is 0x8

[ 06-15 14:07:48.407  4277: 4293 D/vol.VolumeDialogControl.VC ]
isSafeVolumeDialogShowing : false
```

I want to extract some information from the log file.The expected format is below:

```
[('06-15 14:07:48.377', '15012', 'D', 'ViewRootImpl', 'ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0'),
('06-15 14:07:48.397', '3539', '4649', 'D', 'AudioService', 'active stream is 0x8'),
('06-15 14:07:48.407', '4277', '4293', 'D', 'vol.VolumeDialogControl.VC',  'isSafeVolumeDialogShowing : false')]
```

**Question:** What's the best python regex for extracting the expected format infomation? Thanks very much!

**upate:** I have tried the below code

```
import re
regex = r"(\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})\s(\d+).*(\w{1})/(.*)\](.*)"
data = [g.groups() for g in re.finditer(regex, log, re.M | re.I)]
```

The result I have got is

```
data=[('06-15 14:07:48.377', '15012', 'D', 'ViewRootImpl', '\r'), (
'06-15 14:07:48.397', '3539', 'D', 'AudioService', '\r'), ('06-15 14:07:48.407', 
'4277', 'D', 'vol.VolumeDialogControl.VC', '\r')]
```

I can't get the last element.

Comment: Please provide code you have already tried.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted first. Also what you need is to format the strings, since you are using the entire strings.

Comment: The best regex is the one written by yourself so that you could understand it to tweak later if needed.

Comment: @dhdavvie I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
with open('yourlogfile', 'r') as log:
    lines = log.read()
    result = re.sub(r'^\[ (\S+) *(\S+) *(\d+): *(\d+) *([A-Z]+)\/(\S+) \]\n([^\n]+)\n?', 
                    r'\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7', lines, flags=re.MULTILINE)

    print(result)
```

The output:

```
06-15 14:07:48.377 15012 15012 D ViewRootImpl ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0
06-15 14:07:48.397 3539 4649 D AudioService active stream is 0x8
06-15 14:07:48.407 4277 4293 D vol.VolumeDialogControl.VC isSafeVolumeDialogShowing : false
```

---

To get the result as a list of matches use `re.findall()` function:

```
...
result = re.findall(r'^\[ (\S+) *(\S+) *(\d+): *(\d+) *([A-Z]+)\/(\S+) \]\n([^\n]+)\n?', lines, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[('06-15', '14:07:48.377', '15012', '15012', 'D', 'ViewRootImpl', 'ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0'), ('06-15', '14:07:48.397', '3539', '4649', 'D', 'AudioService', 'active stream is 0x8'), ('06-15', '14:07:48.407', '4277', '4293', 'D', 'vol.VolumeDialogControl.VC', 'isSafeVolumeDialogShowing : false')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I also want to ask another question,How can I get result like the below list, I have tried, but I can't get the last element.
[('06-15 14:07:48.377', '15012', 'D', 'ViewRootImpl', 'ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0'), (
'06-15 14:07:48.397', '3539', 'D', 'AudioService', 'active stream is 0x8'), ('06-15 14:07:48.407', 
'4277', 'D', 'vol.VolumeDialogControl.VC', 'isSafeVolumeDialogShowing : false')]

Comment: great, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

input = """
[ 06-15 14:07:48.377 15012:15012 D/ViewRootImpl ]
ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0

[ 06-15 14:07:48.397  3539: 4649 D/AudioService ]
active stream is 0x8

[ 06-15 14:07:48.407  4277: 4293 D/vol.VolumeDialogControl.VC ]
isSafeVolumeDialogShowing : false
"""

# remove carriage return
input = re.sub('(\])\s+', '\\1 ', input)

# replace D/Something ] -> D Something
input = re.sub('([A-Z]{1})/([^\s]+)\s+\]\s+', '\\1 \\2 ', input)

# remove first [
input = re.sub('\[\s+([0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})', '\\1', input)

print input
```

output

```
06-15 14:07:48.377 15012:15012 D ViewRootImpl ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0

06-15 14:07:48.397  3539: 4649 D AudioService active stream is 0x8

06-15 14:07:48.407  4277: 4293 D vol.VolumeDialogControl.VC isSafeVolumeDialogShowing : false
```

Comment: hi, zital, Thank you very much too